# Как разрешить циклические зависимости в Делфи?

Tags: delphi, ооп, delphi-xe5, зависимости

Допустим у нас есть 2 класса, расположенных в разных юнитах:

- `TMaster` - хозяин собаки, который должен о ней знать
- `TDog` - собака, которая должна знать о своем хозяине

Unit_Master:

```
uses Unit_Dog;
type TMaster = class
public
  Dog: TDog;
end;
```

Unit_Dog:

```
uses Unit_Master;
type TDog = class
public
  Master: TMaster;
end;
```

Использование таких прямых ссылок между классами очень облегчило бы жизнь. К сожалению, Delphi не может скомпилировать такой код из-за циклической зависимости между юнитами.

Как грамотно разрулить циклическую зависимость и скомпилировать подобный код, какие есть способы?

Comment: не думали завести общего предка типа TEntity для этих классов? И для ссылок на хозяина/подчиненного использовать именно его. А там, где необходимо - явно приводить тип.

Comment: @kami Сейчас пользуюсь таким вариантом, но он неудобен. Хотелось бы узнать об альтернативных вариантах (помимо кастов, хелперов и объединения в один файл)

Comment: циклическая зависимость в interface-секции в любом случае запрещена. Можно сделать через интерфейсы и использовать поля IMaster / IDog, но проще объединить в один модуль.

Comment: @kami набросал 4 варианта, есть ли другие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант №4

Использовать помощники классов.

(Способ через `private` официально перестал работать с Delphi Seattle (но есть пути как обойти: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351215) и, вероятно, можно будет перейти на `protected`)

Unit_Helper:

```
uses Unit_Master, Unit_Dog;
type
  TMasterHelper = class helper for TMaster
  private
    function GetDog: TDog;
    procedure SetDog(aObject: TDog);
  public
    property Dog: TDog read GetDog write SetDog;
  end;

  TDogHelper = class helper for TDog
  private
    function GetMaster: TMaster;
    procedure SetMaster(aObject: TMaster);
  public
    property Master: TMaster read GetMaster write SetMaster;
  end;

function TMasterHelper.GetDog: TDog;
begin
  Result := fDog;
end;
```

Unit_Master:

```
type TMaster = class
protected
  fDog: TObject;
end;
uses Unit_Helper;
  .. Dog.Bark;
```

Unit_Dog:

```
type TDog = class
protected
  fMaster: TObject;
end;
uses Unit_Helper;
  .. Master.Yell;
```

Минусы в том, что у класса может быть максимум 1 помощник, следовательно воспользоваться этим трюком можно только 1 раз.

Comment: Unit_Dog: в первом случае - опечатка

Comment: @isaev, точно, спасибо!

Comment: а как в таком случае будут геттер и сеттер выглядеть?

Comment: @Isaev дополнил. В т.ч. с уточнениями по Сиэттлу

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать интерфейсы и в классах хранить ссылки на них, а не на объекты:

```pascal
unit EntityInterfaces
type
  IMaster = interface;
  IDog = interface;

  IMaster = interface
  ['{8417E5A8-02FE-4A83-BD0C-F69E79492796}']
    function GetDog: IDog;
    procedure SetDog(const ADog: IDog);

    property Dog: IDog read GetDog write SetDog;
  end;

  IDog = interface
  ['{9B501AD7-BD77-46AC-BC08-545433EC5FFE}']
    function GetMaster: IMaster;
    procedure SetMaster(const AMaster: IMaster);

    property Master: IMaster read GetMaster write SetMaster;
  end;
```

Сами классы в этом случае объявляются так:

```pascal
  TMaster = class(TInterfacedObject, IMaster)
  private
    [Weak]
    FDog: IDog;
    function GetDog: IDog;
    procedure SetDog(const ADog: IDog);
  end;

  TDog = class(TInterfacedObject, IDog)
  private
    [Weak]
    FMaster: IMaster;
    function GetMaster: IMaster;
    procedure SetMaster(const AMaster: IMaster);
  end;
```

И работа ведется уже с интерфейсами:

```pascal
procedure TForm11.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Master: IMaster;
  Dog: IDog;
begin
  Master := TMaster.Create;
  Dog := TDog.Create;

  Master.Dog := Dog;
  Dog.Master := Master;
end; // на выходе из метода Master и Dog будут автоматически удалены,
// поскольку их "циклические ссылки" друг на друга имеют атрибут Weak
// без использования слабых ссылок возникла бы утечка памяти.
```

Недостатки способа:

необходимость дважды описывать методы - в интерфейсе и непосредственно в реализации.

автоудаление объекта при доведении счетчика ссылок до нуля будет непривычно тем, кто не работал с интерфейсами.

---

Для ликвидации последнего недостатка можно сделать собственную реализацию IUnknown и наследовать свои классы не от TInterfacedObject, а от TNoReferenceObject :

```pascal
type
  TNoReferenceObject = class(TObject, IInterface)
    { IInterface }
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; virtual; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  end;

{ TNoReferenceObject }

function TNoReferenceObject.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TNoReferenceObject._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

function TNoReferenceObject._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Подсчет ссылок для всех наследников TNoReferenceObject не будет действовать и все созданные экземпляры нужно будет удалять вручную, как и обычные объекты:

```pascal
procedure TForm11.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Master: IMaster;
  Dog: IDog;
begin
  Master := TMaster.Create;
  Dog := TDog.Create;
  try
    Master.Dog := Dog;
    Dog.Master := Master;
  finally
    TObject(Master).Free;
    TObject(Dog).Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Достаточно сложный вариант. Кстати, не проще ли тогда в 3-м юните объявить 2 абстрактных класса и унаследоваться от них в 1 и 2 юнитах? По крайней мере не надо беспокоиться о счетчике ссылок.

Comment: @Kromster да, это сложно. Собственно, и написал ответ только из-за своего комментария к вопросу. Абстрактные классы... в этом случае это будет почти точная копия ответов №2 и 3

Comment: @kami Авто-удаление объектов это не недостаток, а преимущество. А вот использовать хак с `TNoReferenceObject` вообще не стоит, т.к. это какой-то дикий костыль.

Comment: @zed - если человек не работал с интерфейсами, то для него это будет огромным недостатком. Он скорее всего объявит `Master: TMaster` и будет долго плеваться, почему после `Master.Free` вылезает AV.  Ну а насчет "дикого костыля" - на этом подходе основаны VCL и FMX, начиная с `TComponent` в обоих фреймворках. Так что дикого здесь мало. Да и костыльности тоже нет.

Comment: Тут стоит добавить с какой версии начинает работать  [Weak], ибо компилятор в младших версиях не предупреждает ни о чём, а просто молча игнорит и ты думаешь, что всё хорошо) в XP, например, оно не учитывается.

Answer (score 5):

Вариант №1

Объединить оба класса в 1 файл и воспользоваться `forward declaration`:

Unit:

```
type TDog = class; // т.н. forward declaration

TMaster = class
public
  Dog: TDog;
end;

TDog = class
public
  Master: TMaster;
end;
```

Минусы очевидны - получаем один огроменный файл с кучей кода.

Comment: Использование одного файла имеет еще один побочный эффект, о котором часто забывают - классы становятся дружественными, т.е. могут обращаться напрямую к приватным полям и методам друг друга. Иногда это тоже полюс.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Спасибо за дополнение! *Хотя ИМХО от дружественности как раз надо стараться уходить, в пользу более четких интерфейсов и "черных ящиков".*

Comment: @Kromster Поскольку у вас классы ссылаются друг на друга, у вас уже **всё плохо** и от объединения их в один юнит, сильно хуже не станет. Но лучше поломать голову над архитектурой и постараться разорвать эту зависимость.

Comment: @zed напишете ответ, показывающий, как с минимумом трудозатрат "оторвать" собаку от хозяина?

Comment: @Kromster так ведь для этого надо знать логику вашей программы. Нужно делать так, чтобы собаке небыло необходимости вызывать методы хозяина.

Comment: @zed вобщем-то согласен. Вокруг этого ограничения действительно можно выстроить дизайн приложения (заюзать интерфейсы, эвенты и всё такое). А уж как это сделать - очень широкий вопрос не входящий в рамки SO.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов если это нежелательный побочный эффект, то в новых версиях Delphi от него можно избавиться, используя **strict private** или **strict protected**

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №2

Создать общего предка, с общими методами:

Unit_Entity:

```
type TEntity = class
end;
```

Unit_Dog:

```
uses Unit_Entity;
type TMaster = class(TEntity)
public
  Dog: TEntity;
end;
```

Unit_Dog:

```
uses Unit_Entity;
type TDog = class(TEntity)
public
  Master: TEntity;
end;
```

Минусы в том, что весь код специфический для каждого класса по прежнему остается в каждом классе и недоступен без дополнительных решений.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №3

Использовать общего предка и приводить типы при обращении к объектам:

Unit_Master:

```
type TMaster = class
public
  Dog: TObject;
end;
implementation
uses Unit_Dog;
  .. TDog(Dog).Bark;
```

Unit_Dog:

```
type TDog = class
public
  Master: TObject;
end;
implementation
uses Unit_Master;
  .. TMaster(Master).Yell;
```

Минусы в том, что при каждом обращении нам придется приводить объект к определенному классу. При большом количестве обращений, это загромождает код.

Comment: В этом способе есть такая возможность? TMaster.Dog.Master.Dog.Master... Это не создаст проблем?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Такая возможность есть во всех способах. Проблемы в этом никакой нет, если только вы сами не будете писать явно бессмысленный код типа `newMaster.Dog.Master.Dog.Master.Dog.Master ...`.