# Как в двух различных классах обращаться к свойствам друг друга?

Tags: delphi, ооп, классы

Есть

```
type TA = class 
  ValueA: Integer;
  myFuncA(): Boolean;
end;
```

и

```
type TB = class
  ValueB: Integer;
  myFuncB(): Boolean;
end;
```

Как записать это так, чтобы в myFuncB видеть значение ValueA, и наоборот, в myFuncA видеть ValueB? Не знаю если это важно, сначала создается TA, а он создает TB.

Comment: Передай объект в параметрах метода.

Comment: @Alex78191 я же не могу перекрестно в первом объявить второй и во втором первый

Comment: Почему не можешь?

Comment: Что-то типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625439/

Comment: @Kromster какой-то странный язык

Comment: Зачем создавать два одинаковых класса?

Comment: @Alex78191 я так понимаю, это все из-за однопроходного компилятора. Зато есть приятный бонус - пересборка проекта из миллиона строк за десяток секунд.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо за ссылку, воспользуюсь вашим вариантом N3 за общего предка возьму TObject, Интерфейсы пока для меня сложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо указать области видимости для полей в классах. Переменные которые нужно видеть - объявляются в секции public

пример:

```
type
  TA = class 
  private
    function myfunc(val: Integer): Boolean;
  public  
    ValueA: Integer;
  end;

  TB = class
  public
    fa: TA;
    constructor Create(a: TA);
  end;

...

constructor TB.Create(a: TA);
begin
  inherited;
  fa := a;
end;

...

a := TA.Create();
b := TB.Create(a);
WriteLN(b.fa.ValueA);

...
```

Comment: Я конечно могу ошибаться, но так как я записал, переменные не находятся в private, так как я могу обратиться к ним из вне, проблема в перекрестном обращении

Comment: Тогда - физический смысл данного действия непонятен. Вы создаете две различные сущности и хотите чтобы из одного были видны значения другого.... Дополню ответ

Comment: *"Так как у Вас сделано -переменные находятся в секции private"* - Это не так. Members at the beginning of a class declaration that do not have a specified visibility are **by default published**, provided the class is compiled in the {$M+} state or is derived from a class compiled in the {$M+} state; otherwise, such members are public.

Comment: Да вы правы, подзабыл уже ....