# Как получить доступ из одного класса к свойствам другого?

Tags: delphi, ооп, delphi-xe

Имеем два класса в разных модулях:

```
Unit uClassA;

Interface

Type
  TClassA = Class(TObject)
  Private
    FBlocks: Array Of TBlock;
    Function FGetBlock(Value: Byte): TBlock;
  Public
    ClassB: TClassB;
    Property Block[Index: Byte]: TBlock Read FGetBlock;
  End;

Implementation

End.
```

и ClassB, который создаётся в конструкторе ClassA, после заполнения массива FBlocks

```
Unit uClassB;

Interface

Type
  TClassB = Class(TObject)
  Public
    Procedure SetBlock();
  End;

Implementation

Procedure TClassB.SetBlock();
Begin
  //Тут нужно достучаться до ClassA.Block[Index]
End;

End.
```

Как это правильнее организовать? В голову приходит только сделать пустой класс с этим массивом и от него наследовать эти оба, но правильно ли это?

Comment: Передать как параметр в `SetBlock`?

Comment: Добавьте в `TClassB` поле например `Owner: TClassA` и передавайте в конструкторе указатель на родительский объект.

Comment: @dr. F.I.N. идея хорошая, но перекрёстное объявление получается, мне нужно в Uses uClassA прописать uClassB и наоборот, что нельзя.

Comment: @VTT что-то более общее хочется... понадобится ещё три свойства придётся все передавать параметрами?

Comment: @Isaev добавьте третий модуль, на который будут ссылаться Ваши модули с `TClassA` и `TClass`B. В этом модуле опишите интерфейс `IClassA` с необходимыми методами и реализуйте этот интерфейс в `TClassA`. В конструкторе передавайте ссылку на интерфейс.

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Добавьте код, приведите пример, чего конкретно не хватает. (а также, зачем тут акцент на "после заполнения массива" и что такое "достучаться"?). Также посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625439

Comment: @Kromster ваша ссылка полностью отвечает на вопрос, спасибо. У меня сначала был вариант 2, потом сделал вариант 3, думал как раз переделать через интерейсы, но хелпера, думаю, в моём случае будет вполне достаточно!

Answer (score 0):

```
Unit blockArrayHolder;

Interface

Type
  TBlockArrayHolder = Class(TObject)
  Public
    Data: Array Of TBlock;
  End;

Implementation

End.

Unit uClassA;

Interface

Type
  TClassA = Class(TObject)
  Private
    FBlocks: TBlockArrayHolder;
    Function FGetBlock(Value: Byte): TBlock;
  Public
    constructor Create;
    ClassB: TClassB;
    Property Block[Index: Byte]: TBlock Read FGetBlock;
  End;

Implementation

constructor TClassA.Create;
begin
  FBlocks := TBlockArrayHolder.Create;
  // fill FBlocks.Data
  ClassB := TClassB.Create(FBlocks);
end;

End.

Unit uClassB;

Interface

Type
  TClassB = Class(TObject)
  Private
    FBlocks: TBlockArrayHolder
  Public
    Procedure SetBlock();
    constructor Create(aBlocks: TBlockArrayHolder);
  End;

Implementation

Procedure TClassB.SetBlock();
Begin
  //Тут нужно достучаться до ClassA.Block[Index] - через fBlocks.Data
End;

constructor TClassB.Create(aBlocks: TBlockArrayHolder);
begin
  FBlocks := aBlocks;
end;

End.
```

Comment: Опять простынка кода без единого пояснения ...

Comment: Так прозрачно всё, чего тут пояснять то?)